# Fast Fourier 2D Convolution for Neural Networks

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network, fft

I am stuck on implementing a 2D FFT Convolution on a neural network that I am working on. The shape of my input goes as `X.shape = (100000, 1, 32, 32)`, where the convention here goes like `(instances, channel, height, width)`. I unfortunately ran on some value error and I do not seem to understand why I am getting it. Even my logic tells me that the code should work fine (I am referring specifically to the  error that can be traced on the function build(self, input_shape) that can be found under the FFTConv2D class). What do you guys think about it? I attached the code and the error that I am getting.

```
class FFTConv2D(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, filters, kernel_size, padding="same", strides=1, activation="relu",
                 kernel_initializer='TruncatedNormal', **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.filters = filters
        self.kernel_size = kernel_size
        self.padding = padding
        self.strides = strides
        self.activation = keras.activations.get(activation)
        self.kernel_initializer = keras.initializers.get(kernel_initializer)

    #kernel weights
    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.kernel = self.add_weight(
            shape=(self.kernel_size, self.kernel_size, input_shape[-1], self.filters),
            initializer=self.kernel_initializer,
            trainable=True,
            name="kernel"
        )


    def call(self, inputs): 
        #Apply fft on the input
        x = tf.signal.fft2d(tf.cast(inputs,tf.complex64))

        #Obtain fft of the kernel
        kernel_fft = tf.signal.fft2d(tf.cast(self.kernel, tf.complex64))

        #perform element-wise multiplication/convolution
        x_kernel_fft = tf.multiply(x, kernel_fft)

        #obtain now the inverse transform
        x_kernel = tf.math.real(tf.signal.ifft2d(x_kernel_fft))
        
        return self.activation(x_kernel)

    #Just to make sure we get to save the model later on with this custom convolution
    def get_config(self):
        config = super().get_config()
        config.update({
            "filters": self.filters,
            "kernel_size": self.kernel_size,
            "padding": self.padding,
            "strides": self.strides,
            "activation": keras.activations.serialize(self.activation),
            "kernel_initializer": keras.initializers.serialize(self.kernel_initializer)
        })
        return config

model = Sequential()
model.add(FFTConv2D(32, 3, padding="same", strides = 1, activation="relu", kernel_initializer='TruncatedNormal',
                 input_shape=(1,32,32)))
model.add(FFTConv2D(32, 3, padding="same", strides = 1, activation="relu", kernel_initializer='TruncatedNormal'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), padding="same"))
model.add(FFTConv2D(64, 3, padding="same", strides = 1, activation="relu", kernel_initializer='TruncatedNormal'))
model.add(FFTConv2D(64, 3, padding="same", strides = 1, activation="relu", kernel_initializer='TruncatedNormal'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='TruncatedNormal'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='TruncatedNormal'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', kernel_initializer='TruncatedNormal'))
```

The error that it returns is

```
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "fft_conv2d_2" (type FFTConv2D).

ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 2 and 3 for '{{node fft_conv2d_2/mul}} = Mul[T=DT_COMPLEX64](fft_conv2d_2/FFT2D, fft_conv2d_2/FFT2D_1)' with input shapes: [3,2,16,32], [3,3,32,64].


Call arguments received by layer "fft_conv2d_2" (type FFTConv2D):
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(3, 2, 16, 32), dtype=float32)
```

I understand that the multiplication cannot be carried out because of the difference in the dimension. Are there any ways around this? I would appreciate any form of help you guys would extend. Thanks!

I am quite lost on how to debug it and finding troubles on carrying out the FFT Convolution. There are code snippets online, however, I did the code above from scratch and it could be that I misunderstood how FFT works. However, I am pretty sure that what I implemented was correct.